# Possible to assign a return from a switch case in C#?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

All the examples I've seen of C# switch statements are as follows

```
var variable, result; 

switch (variable) {
 case 1: result = somevalue; break;
 case 2: result = someothervalue; break;
}
```

However, I would like to have something like

```
var result = switch (variable) {
   case 1: return <somevalue>;
   case 2: return <someothervalue>;
  }
```

Possible? (maybe I need `break` inside the cases, but it is a return...)

Comment: You can do the `return` part, but not the `var result = ` part.  But why don't you try it and see?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do.  Let's suppose you can do what you are doing in the second piece of code.  If you do that, you'll lose the value of result.  It does not make any sense for me.

Comment: That's why we use methods. You need to define a method which returns value depends upon the switch case.

Comment: Have you checked official documentation for return value of `switch`? Does it say something like "operator `switch`" or maybe "method `switch`"? It should give you a clue whether it returns value or not. If you need exact details - language grammar is ultimate source of truth. If any of information in sources mentioned above is not clear - update the post and it will be much better fit for SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic idea behind `return <somevalue>` is true but `switch` is a *control statement* so it doesn't `return`s a value. You have to make it a method like this:

```
dynamic SomeMethod(int variable)
{
   switch(variable)
   {
       case 1: return "text";
       case 2: return 5;

       // Or manually return something out of switch scope
       // because the method has to return something
       default: return null;
   }
}

void Test()
{
    // Now you have a value assigned to an variable
    // that comes from SomeMethod
    // which is generated (selected) by switch
    var result1 = SomeMethod(1); // string
    var result2 = SomeMethod(2); // int
    var result3 = SomeMethod(123); // null
}
```

**In this case I also need to explain this:** methods cannot `return` *implicit* types (`var`), because compiler can't guess what is the `return` *type* is. But you can `return` [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) and now type will be changed runtime. Also you can't use `dynamic` in `switch` because it requires a [nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) type.

If you want it short (in method), can create an anonymous method with lambda :)

```
var result =
    (Func<int, dynamic>)
    ( (x) =>
    {
        switch(x)
        {
            case 1: return "text";
            case 2: return 5;
            default: return null;
        }
    } // Lambda
    ) // Func<int, dynamic> (takes int parameters, returns dynamic value)
    (); // Call it and get return value to assign
```

However I strongly advice you to read some articles like [statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx), [methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx), [types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx)...

Answer (score 7):

With c# 8.0 you can use new switch syntax:

```
var area = figure switch 
{
    Line _      => 0,
    Rectangle r => r.Width * r.Height,
    Circle c when c.Radius == 0 => throw new ThrowSomeException(c),
    Circle c    => Math.PI * c.Radius * c.Radius,
    _           => throw new UnknownFigureException(figure)
};
```

You can read more about new feature [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#positional-patterns).

Answer (score 2):

Consider [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
var result =
    variable == 1? <somevalue>:
    variable == 2? <someothervalue>:
    <defaultvalue>;
```

Comment: Like the formatting. Reads much nicer than indenting nested conditions.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to return a value based upon some input, and you look towards a switch as a possible solution, consider a dictionary.

```
// populated with types and data that mean something
// to you. 
private IDictionary<int, string> _lookupDictionary; 

public string GetValue(int variable) {
    return _lookupDictionary[variable];

    // instead of 
    // switch (variable) { 
    //     case 1: 
    //         return <somevalue>; 
    //     case 2:
    //         return <someothervalue>; 
    //     ...
    //     case n-1: 
    //         return <somethingelse>; 
    //     case n: 
    //         return <finalsomething>; 
}
```

Note that the switch itself doesn't return a value. If you want to save that return value as well, then just perform the lookup with a dictionary's indexer as shown, store the reference, then return.

```
private IDictionary<int, string> _lookupDictionary;
private KeyValuePair<int, string> _cache; 

public string GetValue(int variable) {
    if (!_lookupDictionary.ContainsKey(variable)) {
        // throw an exception - or add - behavior dependent 
        // upon your need
    }

    if (_cache.Key == variable) {
        return _cache.Value;
    }

    _cache = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(variable, _lookupDictionary[variable]);
    return _cache.Value;
}
```